# WPF view image hashtag in instagram

Tags: c#, wpf, vb.net, instagram, hashtag

I'm developing an information system based from WPF. The client request to put a gallery function in the system which show all pictures that hashtag #tags with specific name e.g. #ohsemme in Instagram. How to do it? Does it need to have specific permission or API to do this? Please advise.. TQ

Comment: One thing you need to think about is if you want to poll to get results (e.g. once per minute for example) or use Instagram's 'realtime' feature whereby they push new results to you as they occur via a callback URL you specify. http://instagram.com/developer/realtime/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the instagram [API reference](http://instagram.com/developer/). As I see from the API Console there is an /tags/{tag-name} method for that purpose.

Comment: But how to play around with API console?

Comment: @Luiey you need to authorize, because this API requires authentication. At the top of the API Console window you can see the Authentication dropdown. Select an OAuth2 option.

Comment: yes i do login. then at parameters and value, i dont know what to fill. i use "GET" tags on that console

Comment: @Luiey check [that page](http://instagram.com/developer/endpoints/tags/) for parameters and stuff

Comment: Hey, I able to know how many image where tags on it. Now I have to search how to use API integrate to my VB.Net or C#. Thanks man :)